# Compiling Angular 2 project to one app.js file

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I've searched all over the internet in search of an answer: **How do I compile all my Angular 2 code including dependencies to one file.** This has been asked many many times, but I have a different approach. My file tree before starting angular was:

```
public
source
└─── _base
      ├─── sass
      └─── img
└─── _structure
      ├─── sass
      └─── img
├─── gulpfile.js
├─── node_modules
└─── package.json
```

Now my current filetree looks like this:

```
public
source
├─── __components
├─── __directives
├─── __services
└─── _base
      ├─── sass
      └─── img
└─── _structure
      ├─── sass
      └─── img
├─── gulpfile.js
├─── node_modules
└─── package.json
```

The plan was to copy all .ts ending files from `__directives`/`__services`/`__components` folders with gulp, run them through `systemjs` and export one `app.min.js` to the `./public` folder

Is it possible to achieve this with my current setup? (making things complicated with the current file tree setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io).

Comment: will that handle relative paths without the hassle? (plus won't the compilation time be too long to even develop?)

Comment: @MikeDuister: If you're already using SystemJS, using their module bundler might also be a good option: https://github.com/systemjs/builder